# Recover.c using malloc

Tags: c

Using clang I get 2 warnings:

```
warning: passing 'unsigned char *' to parameter of type 'char *' converts between pointers to
      integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
    strncpy(contents, &data[starting_byte], size);
            ^~~~~~~~
 passing argument to parameter '__dest' here
extern char *strncpy (char *__restrict __dest,
                                       ^
 warning: passing 'unsigned char *' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between
      pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
    strncpy(contents, &data[starting_byte], size);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 passing argument to parameter '__src' here
                      const char *__restrict __src, size_t __n)
```

When I run it there are no images recovered. I would really appreciate any help with the code. Ty!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


// Function prototypes. Don't change these.
unsigned char * read_card(char fname[], int *size);
void save_jpeg(unsigned char data[], int starting_byte, int size, char fname[]);
void recover(unsigned char data[], int size);

int main()
{
    // Read the card.raw file into an array of bytes (unsigned char)
    int card_length;
    unsigned char *card = read_card("card.raw", &card_length);

    // Recover the images
    recover(card, card_length);
}
//read the card.raw file, returns array of unsigned char(bytes)
unsigned char * read_card(char fname[], int *size)
{

    struct stat st;
    if (stat(fname, &st) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't get info about %s\n", fname);
        exit(1);
    }
    int len = st.st_size;
    unsigned char *raw = (unsigned char *)malloc(len * sizeof(unsigned char));

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s for reading\n", fname);
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[512];
    int r = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (fread(buf, 1, 512, fp))
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        {
            raw[r] = buf[i];
            r++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    *size = len;
    return raw;
}
//parameters: array of unsigned char(bytes),has data for a single pic
//length of the data and name of the file to save to
void save_jpeg(unsigned char data[], int starting_byte, int size, char fname[])
{
    unsigned char *contents = (unsigned char *)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char));

    strncpy(contents, &data[starting_byte], size);
    contents[size + 1] = '\0';

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't write to %s\n", fname);
        exit(1);
    }

    fwrite(contents, 1, size, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    free(contents);
}

void recover(unsigned char data[], int size)
{
  int count = 0;
  int block = 512;
  int byte_offset = 0;
  int starting_byte = 0;
  bool image_wraps = false;

  for (int leading_byte = 0; leading_byte < size; leading_byte+=block)
  {
    if (image_wraps == false) {
      //check for beginning signatures
      if (data[leading_byte] == 0xff && data[leading_byte+1] == 0xd8 && data[leading_byte+2] == 0xff &&
        (data[leading_byte+3] == 0xe0 || data[leading_byte+3] == 0xe1)) 
      {
        //store start
        starting_byte = leading_byte;
        for (int current_byte = leading_byte + 4; current_byte < leading_byte + block - 1; ++current_byte)
        {
            if (data[current_byte] == 0xff && data[current_byte+1] == 0xd9)
            {
              char filename[30];
              snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%03d.jpg", ++count);
              save_jpeg(data, starting_byte, current_byte - leading_byte, filename);
            }
        }
        image_wraps = true;
        byte_offset = block;
      }
    }
    // image wraps to multiple blocks
    else {
      for (int current_byte = leading_byte; current_byte < leading_byte + block - 1; ++current_byte)
      {
        if (data[current_byte] == 0xff && data[current_byte+1] == 0xd9)
        {
          char filename[30];
          snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%03d.jpg", ++count);
          printf("leading %i, current %i, c-l+o %i\n", leading_byte, current_byte, byte_offset);
          save_jpeg(data, starting_byte, current_byte - leading_byte + byte_offset, filename);
          image_wraps = false;
          starting_byte = 0;
          byte_offset = 0;
        }
      }
      if (byte_offset > 0) {
          byte_offset += block;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("How many images?: %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `strncpy`. http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` operates on C style strings.  Unsigned char arrays are not C-style strings, null terminated char arrays are.

This means that you will likely do better to `memcpy` the data between the arrays (as they both match in type) instead of using `strcpy`.

Comment: Ty! Will try that.

Comment: I do not get warnings anymore, however still no images recovered. Any help on that pls?

Comment: Sounds like the warning was not related to the failure you observed.  Perhaps you should add some debugging and narrow the scope of the code you believe is not working.

Comment: It's either not finding the starting signatures or doesn't ever enter the if loop   "if (data[leading_byte] == 0xff && data[leading_byte+1] == 0xd8 && data[leading_byte+2] == 0xff &&
        (data[leading_byte+3] == 0xe0 || data[leading_byte+3] == 0xe1)) "

Comment: @SierraCollege I'd use a hex editor to inspect the input file.  Verify that the signatures are correct.  If they are correct, then you either have a problem with the reading (possible, but improbable) or the storage from the read (could happen, especially if there are signed / unsigned mismatches), or the byte order as presented in your program is different than the presentation of the byte order in the data file.